# Conditional expectations and variance - OLS

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, expected-value, conditional

Apologies for starting a new post for such basic problems but I have an exam tomorrow and struggle to sort out two answers from last year's exam (2. and 3.). I gave as much context as possible:

The question is considering a simple regression model $y_i = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_i+u_i$

I am given:

$\mathbb{E}[x]=5$ ;
$\mathbb{E}[y]=5$;
$Var(x)=20$;
$Var(u|x)=10$; $\mathbb{E}[u|x]=0$;
$\beta_1=2$

$\textbf{1. What is the true value of $\beta_0$}$

I solve this using $\beta_0=\bar{y}-\beta_1\bar{x} = 5-2*5=-5$

$\textbf{2. What is $var(y|x)$}$

I use the conditional variance formula

$Var(y|x)=\mathbb{E}[y^2|x]-\left(\mathbb{E}[y|x]\right)^2$

$Var(y|x)=\mathbb{E}[y^2|x]-\left(\mathbb{E}[\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x+u]\right)^2$

$Var(y|x)=\mathbb{E}[y^2|x]-\left(\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}\bar{x}\right)^2$

However I am not familiar with the term $\mathbb{E}[y^2|x]$?

$\textbf{3. What is $var(y)$}$

$Var(y)=\mathbb{E}[y^2]-\mathbb{E}[y]^2$

Using the law of iterated expectations:

$Var(y)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[y^2|x]]-\mathbb{E}[y]^2$

Therefore I will be able to solve once I know how to handle question 2.

$\textbf{4. What is $Cov(x,y)$ when $Cov(x,u)=0$}$

$Cov(x,y)=\mathbb{E}[xy]-\mathbb{E}[y]\mathbb{E}[y]$

Using the law of iterated expectations:

$Cov(x,y)=\mathbb{E}[x\mathbb{E}[y|x]]-\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[y]$

$Cov(x,y)=\mathbb{E}[x(\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x+u)]-\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[y]$

$Cov(x,y)=\beta_{0}\bar{x}+\beta_{1}\mathbb{E}[x^2]-5*5$

Then I use $Var(x)=\mathbb{E}[x^2]-(\mathbb{E}[x])^2 \implies \mathbb{E}[x^2]=20+25=45$

$Cov(x,y)=-5*5+2*45-5*5=40$

does it make sense?

Thank you in advance, I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2**) $var(y|x)=var(\beta_0+\beta_1x+u|x)=var(u|x)=10$

**3**) Use total law of variance: $$var(y)=E[var(y|x)]+var(E[y|x])=10+var(\beta_0+\beta_1x)=10+\beta_1^2var(x)$$

**4**) Here is another method:

$$cov(x,y)=cov(x,\beta_0+\beta_1x+u)=\beta_1var(x)+cov(x,u)=40$$

A note on your solutions: $\bar{x}$ is sample mean while $E[x]$ is population mean and they're not equal. Here, you don't have $\bar{x}$, instead use $E[x]=\mu_x$.